# Run CMD.exe prompt through Visual Studio using quoted arguments

Tags: c#, visual-studio, cmd, visual-studio-2017

I am trying to run a SQLpackage.exe prompt through visual studio to aid in an automation process.  I have tested the string in command prompt and it runs fine.  When I run it through VS17 I get a prompt that opens/closes and nothing happens.  What can I do to make this work?

Just for clarification, the string I wish to use in the command line should read as follows:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\sqlpackage" /a:PUBLISH /sf:"C:\targetdacpac.dacpac" /tsn:"(local)\SQL2016" /tdn:"DBtargpath"`

And my string outputted to the console using:

`Console.WriteLine(@"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\sqlpackage"" /a:PUBLISH /sf:""C:\targetdacpac.dacpac"" /tsn:""(local)\SQL2016"" /tdn:""DBtargpath""");`

Returns:

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\sqlpackage" /a:PUBLISH /sf:"C:\targetdacpac.dacpac" /tsn:"(local)\SQL2016" /tdn:"DBtargpath"`

My code is attached below. I am not too familiar with running command line arguments through VS, but I've done enough research to know that my case is rather unique as it contains so many string literals.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

        try {
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("CMD.EXE");
            startInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;

            startInfo.Arguments = @"""C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\sqlpackage"" /a:PUBLISH /sf:""C:\targetdacpac.dacpac"" /tsn:""(local)\SQL2016"" /tdn:""DBtargpath""";

            Process.Start(startInfo);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
        }
```

EDIT: It looks like I'm getting an error because of the spacing in the file path.  When sending multiple string literals it isn't working properly.  I'll keep digging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem over many days of testing.  I still haven't a solution directly to my original problem but simply compiling the commands in a .bat is a working solution.

`"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\sqlpackage" /a:PUBLISH /sf:"C:\targetdacpac.dacpac" /tsn:"(local)\SQL2016" /tdn:"DBtargpath"
PAUSE`

The pause keeps the terminal open so remove it if you don't need it. I used it for testing purposes so I could see the output and be sure my command was working properly.

```
try 
{
    ProcessStartInfo processStart = new ProcessStartInfo("Cmd.exe")
    {
        UseShellExecute = false,
        RedirectStandardInput = true, //shows output in VS
        Arguments = @"/k C:\DacPacs\runcmd.bat"
    };
    Process process = new Process() { StartInfo = processStart };

    process.Start();

}
catch (Exception e)
{
        Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a backslash before the quotes that are part of the string and you will be ready to go

```
startInfo.Arguments = "This \" is ok";
```

Finally

> This " is ok

will be the parameter

Comment: If I'm using string literals with the @ symbol, it uses the correct string.  I'm just not sure why the terminal does nothing with it.  I've outputted the string that is stored and its correct. If I put slashes before the quotes, then I would need to remove the @. I've tried both ways, honestly. Maybe I messed up somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of specifying ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe"), how about ProcessStartInfo(@"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\SQLDB\DAC\140\SqlPackage.exe")?

Or, in the alternative, you can use the Microsoft.SqlServer.Dac API directly. NuGet package is here: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.SqlServer.DacFx.x64